# SVG links and search engines crawling

Tags: seo, svg, search-engine

I have a question about links that coded directly in SVG. For example, a menu. Are they so-called SEO friendly? Will search engines recognize them or I have to duplicate them in HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google indexes it. http://searchengineland.com/google-search-now-indexes-crawls-svg-files-49695